# Error while launching Compute Emulator for Azure in eclipse

Tags: jsp, azure

hi 
I have been trying to run a simple HelloWorld.jsp in Azure . 
I have folowed the link http://java.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/deploying-a-java-application-to-windows-azure-with-eclipse as it is .

But when i launch the DisplayEmulatorUI.cmd ,i get an error:

> "Synchronisation failed .There was no
>   endpoint listening at
>   net.pipe://localhost/dfService/1/DevelopmentFabric
>   that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
>   present, for more details."

cannot understand why is this happening .How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This should run the Windows Azure Compute Emulator... If it does not work, you can always start it manually from the Start Menu.

Maybe you need to run Eclipse as Administrator for the CMD script to work (it is the case with Visual Studio).